# Showing flash messages with Redux on Android

Tags: java, android, architecture, redux

I am trying to make a demo Android project using Redux architecture but I am having trouble to wrap my head around showing flash messages for example as a reaction to successful/failed async action.

If it was a long-lived view, that informs user about the result I would just dispatch another action which alters state with particular flag and display the view. However if I want to use Toast or SnackBar for it, I don't have means to cancel the flag and it would just show the message again after another state change.

I am new to Redux, but I read that reducers ***must*** be pure functions and if I understand the pure function concept correctly, showing a flash message is a side-effect which is not allowed. So I can't dispatch an action that would be reduced to only invoke without altering the state.

So the only option I can see is that I handle all async operations outside the Redux flow, dispatch actions in reaction to those events and show flash messages in event handlers as well. But to my mind, ***every UI change***  is also a ***change in state***, and not reflecting it in Store is a ***problem***. So by doing this I feel like violating Redux pattern and taking a lot from the architecture itself as it will reduce its testing capabilities.

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 0):

Redux describe a component such Middleware.
http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Quote from article:
'It provides a third-party extension point between dispatching an action, and the moment it reaches the reducer.'

You can create middleware for this side effect. In your system you have actions such as SetSuccessLoadingAction and SetFailedLoadingAction. In your middleware you can determine these actions and do what you need.

For example you can see how middleware works for another side affect - logging every incomming action.
https://github.com/zyvpeople/Redux